# When does JDBC setNetworkTimeout() triggers?

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I encountered several stuck JDBC connections in my code due to poor network health. I am planning **java.sql.Connection.setNetworkTimeout** library function. As per docs:-

> Sets the maximum period a Connection or objects created from the Connection will wait for the database to reply to any one request

Now, what exactly is the request here? my query takes really long time to respond and even longer time to process (I am using jdbc interface to a big data DB). So do I need to keep this timeout time, bigger than the expected query execution time (to prevent false trigger) or will there exist keep alive messages, being exchanged to keep track on network connection?, in which case I will keep it really low

Comment: So I want to make sure that I understand your question: you have a slow query and you are already using `Statement.setQueryTimeout()` to ensure the JDBC driver will not cancel the query until it completes. However there happen to be network partitions/problems that cause your connections to break (firewall terminates them?) and you would like to enforce some sort of KEEP ALIVE policy on DB connections yet at the same time have a safeguard to close obviously staled connections?

Comment: @RafalG.  Right on the spot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if your NetworkTimeout is smaller than the QueryTimeout, the query will be terminated on your side - thread that waits for the DB to reply (notice that setNetworkTimeout has `Executor executor` parameter) will be interrupted. Depending on the underlying implementation NetworkTimeout **may** cancel the query on the DB side as well.

If NetworkTimeout > QueryTimeout, and query completes within QueryTimeout then nothing bad should happen. If problems you experience are exactly in this case, you should try to work on the OS level settings for keeping TCP connections alive so that no firewall terminates them too soon.

When it comes to keeping TCP connections alive it is usually more a matter of the OS level settings than the application itself. You can read more about it (Linux) [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html).

Comment: So I keep NetworkTimeOut bigger than query timeout and handle network interruptions at TCP. Thank I got it